# Input not working with step and min attributes in my form

Tags: html

I have an input field that will input a whole number like 1,2,3,4,5,etc.. No decimals and no negative numbers.

I have this but I can still enter in decimal and negative number?

```
<input name="Quantity" type="number" step="1" min="0" class="form-control">
```

Am I supposed to do some validation on the JS side or something to see if the element attribute conditions are met?

P.S. one thing to note. I'm not calling any submit on the form. I'm clicking a button, serializing the form and passing it to a post call via JS.

Comment: You need put inside a form tag for html5 validation to working.

Comment: I have it inside a form tag. I'm just not submitting the form. Please refer to my P.S. above

Comment: If your are talking about plain HTML validation, you need a button doing submit inside your form to trigger the form validation.

Comment: you can call `form.checkValidity()` on your form DOM node to check if if input is validate or not, but the input field wouldn't show error message about the invalid inputs value, but the Submit button will trigger error message,

Answer (score -2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js" integrity="sha256-slogkvB1K3VOkzAI8QITxV3VzpOnkeNVsKvtkYLMjfk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function testValidate() {
            var form = $('form')[0];

            if (!form.checkValidity || !form.checkValidity()) {
                console.log('Invalid');
            } else {
                console.log('Validated');
            };
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>  
    <form id="form1">
        <input id="input1" name="Quantity" type="number" step="1" min="0" class="form-control">
        <div>
            <button>Submit Button</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <button id="btnTest" onclick="testValidate()">TestButton</button>
</body>
</html>
```

You can certainly doing validation check using JS, if you don't want using form submit for validation.

But without seeing your code, I think that you should be able to have your submit button trigger the validation automatically for you, doing your form serializing  after its been validated.

Comment: Getting no further feedback, I am update my code to show how to check element condition are meet with the `Test button`, and what I mean that some form of submit button inside the form need to show validation message.